# SQL Duration Column

Tags: sql, timestamp, odbc, data-conversion, servicenow

I'm trying to convert a duration column which is in a Date/Time format to minutes Integer.

so for 8 Hours the data looks like this 01/01/1970 08:00:00 what can I do to convert to 480 minutes

I'm connecting to Service Now DB through a ODBC connector

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you can use:

```
select extract(hour from duration) * 60
```

If you wanted to include minutes as well:

```
select extract(hour from duration) * 60 + extract(minute from duration)
```

However, date/time functions vary significantly depending on the underlying database.  So, you may need to tweak the above logic.